# What is the difference between `extends A` and `extends typeof A` in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I was make a class decorator and I wanted to limit this decorator could only be applied to certain classes so I did:

```
@decorator()
class A {
    foo:string;
}
@decorator()
class B extends A {

}
@decorator()
class C {}

function decorator () {
  // This makes decorators work on class A and B except class C
  return function<T extends typeof A> (target:T) {}
  // This makes decorators become error on all the classes
  // return function<T extends A> (target:T) {}
}
```

If I changed the `function<T extends typeof A> (target:T) {}` into `function<T extends A> (target:T) {}` then all the decorators would became errors.

I'm not sure why do I have to use `extends typeof A` instead of `extends A`? And what's the difference between them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of class when used as a type means instances of that class. To get the type of a class *constructor*, you use `typeof`.

So:

```
class A {}
const instance: A = new A()

const aConstructor: typeof A = A
const anotherInstance: A = new aConstructor()
```

So the reason that your decorator requires `typeof A` is because it operates on a class constructor, and not instances.

Comment: What does this line mean `const anotherInstance: new aConstructor()`? Should that be `const anotherInstance: aConstructor`?

Comment: I'm sorry for the typo! going to fast tonight. I've updated the answer. It's illustrating that `typeof A` is the type that would allow you create a new class.